# Определить тип ошибки в предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь, причастный-оборот, типы-ошибок

**Наша компания дает возможность покупать оригинальные запчасти для дорожной техники Wirtgen по приемлемой цене, продлевающие срок работы машин.**

Часть "продлевающие срок работы машин" находится не на своем месте, нарушена последовательность изложения.
Как называются такие ошибки (в плане, синтаксические и т. д.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это грамматическая ошибка, связанная с нарушением в построении предложения с причастным оборотом (причастный оборот находится в отрыве от определяемого слова).

[Классификация грамматических ошибок - Материалы для подготовки к вступительным экзаменам в СГГА](https://sites.google.com/a/ssga.ru/ssga4school/rus/rus-teor/glava-6)

Правильный вариант: Наша компания дает возможность покупать оригинальные запчасти для дорожной техники Wirtge, продлевающие срок работы машин, по приемлемой цене.